# Eigenvalues of a special block matrix associated with strongly connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, linear-algebra

### Definition

Let $G=(V,E,A)$ be a **strongly connected** directed graph, where $V=\{1,2,...,n\}$ denotes the vertex set, $E$ is the edge set, and $A$ is the associated adjacency matrix with $0-1$ weighting, that is $a_{i,j}=1$ if $(j,i)\in E$, and $a_{i,j}=0$ otherwise.

$B$ and $D$ are two diagonal matrices, where $b_{ii}=\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}$ and $d_{ii}=\sum_{j=1}^na_{j,i}$. In other words, the diagonal entries of $B$ are the row sum of $A$, and the diagonal entries of $D$ are the column sum of $A$.

### Problem

Now define a new matrix 
$$M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
B-A, & -A \\\\
A-B, & D
\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{2n\times 2n}$$ Since the column sum of $M$ are identical zeros, zero must be one of its eigenvalue. Can I **claim** that the rest eigenvalues all have positive real parts?

I tried many numerical examples, the rest eigenvalues all have positive real parts. Anyone can help prove or disprove the above claim? (Gershgorin Circle Theorem does not apply here because $M$ is not diagonally dominate)

Some facts: Both $(B-A)$ and $(D-A)$ have exactly one zero eigenvalue and all the rest eigenvalues lie in the open right half complex plane because the directed graph is strongly connected. In particular, $(B-A)$ is called the Laplacian matrix of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

I think your claim is true. Taking your matrix $M$ and multiplying from the left by $$H=\begin{bmatrix}
I, & 0 \\\
-I, & I
\end{bmatrix},$$ and from the right by its transpose, 
$$H^t=\begin{bmatrix}
I, & -I \\\
0, & I
\end{bmatrix},$$ the eigenvalues don't change, yet the matrix you get is
$$HMH^t=\begin{bmatrix}
B-A, &B \\\
0, & D-A
\end{bmatrix}.$$
The eigen values of the above matrix are those of $B-A$ and those of $D-A$ and are all non-negative as you already explained.

Comment: Something seems to be amiss here: $HMH^{T}$ has the same inertia as $M$ but the eigenvalues do change. Maybe you meant $H^{-1}$, which is also a nice block matrix?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't completely awake when writing my comment. It has several quite embarrassing mistakes..

Answer (score 1):

the answer was essentially correct but i believe H should be defined as H11=H21=H22=1 and H12=0.

the resulting matrix HMH^T is block upper triangular with B-A and D-A on the diagonal, hence
is hurwitz stable.

although the eigenvalues change, the inertia theorem guarantees that their stability type
cannot change, i.e. they cannot cross the imaginary axis.

Comment: But $M$ is non-symmetric. I don't think you can apply the inertia theorem. There ought to be some way to fix the argument, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Hi, Felix. Do you have any suggestions on how to handle this problem? All the answers posted here are not correct. 

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a counterexample. Try this:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

When I construct $M$ I get a pair of conjugate complex eigenvalues in its spectrum.

Comment: Hi, Felix. Thanks again. I calculate the eigenvalues of M by the following matlab code
%%
A = [1 1 0 1;
     0 1 1 0;
     1 0 1 0;
     0 1 0 1];
B = diag([3,2,2,2]);
D = diag([2,3,2,2]);
M = [B-A, -A; A-B, D];
eig(M)
%%
The result is 
  -0.0000          
   0.3501 + 0.8344i
   0.3501 - 0.8344i
   1.3820          
   2.0000          
   2.7600          
   3.6180          
   3.5398
%%
Yes, the eigenvalues have a pair of conjugate complex eigenvalues. But all the eigenvalues have positive real parts except the zero eigenvalue. So this is not a counterexample.

Comment: @ZhangChanghe: Oops, my bad. I'll look again.